# Doctrine in Symfony2 multiple inserts time out

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to create many of the same object in my database, to insert some users, more exactly. First, I tried flushing the entity manager after every loop, but it didn't work. After some research, I found out that I can do it with batches, so I tried flushing every 15 loops, but I still get timed out after 30 seconds(around 180 queries). Shouldn't these be fast, or almost instant for a number as small as 200-250? How can I make this not time out and insert them faster?

What my function does is make a request to randomuser.me and retrieves a json of users. I retrieve that data into an array and use it to fill my users info with it. I also have a $fields array somewhere that has certain medical fields(won't post it here as it is just an array of plain text). It also adds a related settings entry for the user entry(containing the field in which the medic works and his picture).

```
 public function generateAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $generated = 0;

        $url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=250&nat=us";
        $str = file_get_contents($url);
        $medics = json_decode($str);


   $medicsgruop = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MedAppBundle:Group')->findOneBy(array('name' => 'medics'));

    if (!$medicsgruop) {
        $medicsgruop = new Group('medics');
        $medicsgruop->addRole('ROLE_MEDIC');
        $em->persist($medicsgruop);
        $em->flush();
    }
        $batchSize = 15;
        foreach ($medics->results as $i => $medic) {

            if ($this->fields[$i]) {
                $field = $this->fields[$i];
            } else {
                $field = array_rand($this->fields);
            }

            $fname = $medic->user->name->first;
            $lname = $medic->user->name->last;

            $image = $medic->user->picture->large;
            $email = $medic->user->email;

            $user = new User();
            //user
            $user->setUsername($lname.$fname);
            $user->setFirstname($fname);
            $user->setLastname($lname);
            $user->setEmail($email);
            $user->setEnabled(true);
            $user->setPlainPassword($fname.$lname);
            //group



            $user->addGroup($medicsgruop);
            $em->persist($user);
            //MEDIC SETTINGS
            $medsett = new MedicSettings();
            $medsett->setField($field);
            $medsett->setProfile($image);
            $medsett->setMedic($user);
            $em->persist($medsett);


            if (($i % $batchSize) == 0) {
                $em->flush();
                $em->clear();
            }
        }
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear();
        return $this->render(
            '@MedApp/Admin/generatemedics.html.twig',
            array('generated' => $generated, 'medics' => 'asd')
        );
    }
```

When using the batch method, around 40 users are being added to my database, but it stops after the maximum execution time is reached. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe just add http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: That won't insert all of my records, it will stop after reaching it. I'm looking for a way to insert everything there is.

Comment: there is no other chance as there's no real bulk insert for doctrine (use native query, db-specific functionality or something similar). the only thing you could check in addition to your already right approach of looping through: check whether you're in dev environment having all doctrine debug logging etc. on - this consumes a lot of time. When I did something similar in 'production' the amount of time consumed decreased drastically.

Comment: I ran this in production environment as well, it is the same.

Comment: You run batch script from the browser instead from cli, that's you doing wrong.

Comment: @malcolm mind explaining? This is a Symfony controller that runs on the server. Nothing runs on the browser, I just make the call to the randomuser api, but that is fast.

Comment: By default CLI have time limit set to 0, that mean you never got timeout. Make you sript as console command and run from CLI instead from browser.

Comment: OK maybe you could do some optimization in your loop (you are checking that the "medics" group exists in each iteration!) but i'm not sure that it will make a huge difference. As user2883814 suggested you can call set_time_limit(2) in your loop (not just at the beginning of your script!). This will give 2 seconds for each iteration, that should be enough.

Comment: @Derek that did solve it, but it is very, very slow. I'll tri the CLI suggestion from malcolm. It is pretty annoying, though. I kind of wanted this to be done through the browser. I did fix the medics thing, let me put it outside of the loop. That wasn't the problem as it still runs slow.

Comment: For this kind of batch, CLI is the way to go. But the performance will be the same as with the web version. The difference is that there is no timeout by default with CLI.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc - I'm not telling that'll be faster, just this is proper way for batch scripts. If you think it's slow, so maybe you have some time (requests/sec) limits in db config.

Comment: A performance improvement would be to make sure that the "medics" group exists before running the loop and store its instance in a variable.

Comment: Writing my previous comment i just found out that you are using the $medics variable for multiple usages (json_decode and group object). Change this variable name for one of these !!

Comment: Yes, I removed the check outside the loop. I also changed the variable. Please refresh.

Comment: Are you sure that the loop is the actual performance bottleneck ? Can't it be the file_get_contents of an external URL ? You should benchmark your code to find this out.

Comment: I am very sure, the get_contents is very fast.

Comment: Can you make sure that the $em->flush() is the most time consuming call too ? It seems obvious that it is, but in this kind of situation only a real benchmark can be of any help. Your storage is innoDB, right ? Do transactions work fine ?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc i'm curious if you found the issue. The more i think of it, the more i suspect that your storage engine is MyIsam, or that transactions are disabled for some reason.

Comment: Yes, I used the CLI as @malcolm suggested. Answered with it. The command still runs slow, though. Like ~1 second per user. And they are inserted in the DB 15 at a time, per batch.

Comment: but are you sure that transactions are working (no auto-commit, no MyISAM) ? Do you insert the rows in an empty table or is the table huge already ?

Comment: it is empty. I'm using the latest version of Xampp for my database.

Comment: I don't use XAMPP but it seems that the default storage engine is MyISAM, not innoDB. This means that transactions won't work and that your script does not really make batch inserts. Check your settings, maybe you need to convert your storage to innoDB.

Comment: innoDB is the default storage engine for xampp since 5 years. I checked and I already have it enabled. I am pretty sure that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using malcolm's suggestion to use the Client command from symfony. The command still runs slow, though. Like ~1 second per user. And they are inserted in the DB 15 at a time, per batch.

```
class GenMedicsCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('doctrine:generate:medics')
            ->setDescription('Generate medics group, users, group-users, medic settings')
            ->addArgument(
                'number',
                InputArgument::REQUIRED,
                'How many medics to generate?'
            );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $number = $input->getArgument('number');
        $this->generate($number,$output);

    }


    protected $fields = array(
        'Abdominal Radiology Radiology-Diagnostic',
        'Addiction Psychiatry Psychiatry',
        'Adolescent Medicine Pediatrics'    
    );

    //generate random medics for the win
    public function generate($nr,   OutputInterface $output)
    {


        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');

        $generated = 0;

        $url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=".$nr."&nat=us";
        $str = file_get_contents($url);
        $medics = json_decode($str);

        $medicsgruop = $doctrine->getRepository('MedAppBundle:Group')->findOneBy(array('name' => 'medics'));

        if (!$medicsgruop) {
            $medicsgruop = new Group('medics');
            $medicsgruop->addRole('ROLE_MEDIC');
            $em->persist($medicsgruop);
            $em->flush();
        }

        $batchSize = 15;
        foreach ($medics->results as $i => $medic) {
         //   set_time_limit(2);


            $randkey = array_rand($this->fields);
            $field = $this->fields[$randkey];

            $fname = $medic->user->name->first;
            $lname = $medic->user->name->last;

            $image = $medic->user->picture->large;
            $email = $medic->user->email;

            $user = new User();
            //user
            $user->setUsername($lname.$fname);
            $user->setFirstname($fname);
            $user->setLastname($lname);
            $user->setEmail($email);
            $user->setEnabled(true);
            $user->setPlainPassword($fname.$lname);
            //group


            $user->addGroup($medicsgruop);

            $em->persist($user);
            //MEDIC SETTINGS
            $medsett = new MedicSettings();
            $medsett->setField($field);
            $medsett->setProfile($image);
            $medsett->setMedic($user);
            $em->persist($medsett);
            $output->write(array($i+1,'|',$fname,'|',$lname,'|',$field,'|',$email,'|',$image));
            $output->writeln('');
            if (($i % $batchSize) == 0) {
                $em->flush();
                //  $em->clear();
            }
        }
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear();


        $output->writeln('done');
    }

}
```